# What happened to Firefox browse by name service in location bar?

Tags: firefox

I just updated the Firefox package in Ubuntu 10.04 and Firefox 9.0.1 was installed. The address bar no longer works as it once did (using Google's browse by name service), now all it does is use Google normal search service.

Seeing that there is another search bar in Firefox, just to find stuff in Google (and other search engines), what's the point of this? Is there a usability advantage that I'm currently not seeing? I know all you have to do is add http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=  to the keyword.URL in the about:config preference page.

I just want to know if this is a bug, a thought decision, or something that just slipped past the usability testers. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's primarily a Mozilla issue. While someone here may be able to answer authoritatively, you may also try asking at http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/home or http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.support.firefox/topics?hl=en&gvc=2 or even http://forums.mozillazine.org/index.php.

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't really related to Ubuntu, so you might get a better answer elsewhere, but yes, it is intentional and not a bug. The reason the have the second search bar is that you can use it to search other services like yahoo, ebay, and wikipidea.